# Custom File Format not recognized on device

Tags: android, file, android-intent, mime-types

I have a custom file format (`.ft`) in my android app that i registered in my manifest as an intent filter for some activity as

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
         android:host="*"
         android:mimeType="application/ft"
         android:scheme="content" />

</intent-filter>
```

In the simulator, I am able to tap on the file (for instance when it is being set via email), and the app launches, as expected.

However recently I have been packaging my app as an APK and distributed this for some testing, and on no device the file format is recognized, even though my app is installed … Is there anything I am missing to register the file format?

**Update**
After fiddling around a bit more, it appears like I can open these files from Android mail, but they are not recognized from the gmail app or directly from the file system … Odd.

Comment: Did you find a conclusive answer?  I am wondering the same right now...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `android:host="gmail-ls"` and `android:scheme="file"` in your **intent-filter** if you want to open them in Gmail.